# Does the Stockholm Card covers all public transportation by boat/ferry?

Tags: public-transport, ferries, stockholm

I'm going to Stockholm as a tourist and I'm trying to decide if I should buy a Stockholm Card, a SL Card, or none. I'm very inclined to buying the Stockholm Card, but I couldn't get the information if the card covers for all the public ferries/boats. The [official site](http://www.visitstockholm.com/en/Stockholmcard/) states the following:

> Yes, an unlimited number of free trips on subways, buses, commuter trains, trams and boats with SL Sjövägen are included in the Stockholm Card.

I don't know what exactly it means saying "boats with SL Sjövägen". In [sl.se](http://sl.se) I found the location of various boat/ferry stations, including one in Gamla Stan that would be the best place for me to take it. But when I go to http://www.sjovagen.nu/web/page.aspx?refid=2 there is just one route. I wonder if this is the only route the card covers, or it covers from all stations?

Also, can people get a good view of the city using this kind of transportation?

I'm going in the winter, in February.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like the route you found is the only one that is covered with the Stockholm Card. [This Stockholm Card folder](http://www.sj.se/content/1/c6/17/57/52/SVE_kartfolder_2014_k5_26nov.pdf) (in Swedish) says that it includes unlimited travel with SL, but

> Obs! Djurgårdsfärjan är inte en del av SL.
>
> (Note! The Djurgården-ferry is not a part of SL.)

which I believe is the ferry you found from Slussen in Gamla Stan. You can however buy single tickets at the boat stop and the boats are included in a regular SL card.

Concerning your decision on which card to buy I would say that it depends on how many attractions and museums you are planning on visiting (and how much you value the hassle free luxury of having everything included).

I'd be hard pressed to get in enough admittance fees in one day to make up for the 525-115 = 410 SEK difference between the Stockholm Card and the SL card. But if you are planning to buy a multiple day card and/or are thinking of going to a few of the more expensive museums or attractions it might be worth it.

Comment: I've checked wikipedia [here](http://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Djurgårdsfärjan) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_transport_in_Stockholm#Boat) and it seems the Djurgården is in fact the ferry from Slussen. Since it's not covered in the card it probably won't compensate for me. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Just to add as I can't edit the previous comment, but [this link](http://www.waxholmsbolaget.se/visitor/djurgarden-ferry/maps-ferry-terminals/) is also useful.

Answer (score 2):

The SL ferry is not covered, but the #80 ferry [[timetable linked]](http://sl.se/ficktid/vinter/V80.pdf), is. Depending where you stay, and where you wish to go, that can be very handy.

We spent 4 days in Stockholm and most certainly saved money using the Stockholm Card, but we are very fond of museums and started early in the morning.

Comment: We are staying 4 days and we are planning on going to the main museums only. The #80 ferry seems to be the one I found the route on the Sjövägen website. If it's the only one covered, unfortunately it will be a very limited option. I will still factor what is the best option. Thanks.